# jquery not work correctly when using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am a beginner at ajax and jquery and I am facing a problem with my jquery code. When I post some data from this form to php page, After the result is returned from php, the jquery does not do anything.

code is given below, please help.

```
<h2> Add New Offer</h2>
<form method="post" id="postoffer" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Add Offer</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>Offer Name:</td><td><input  type="text" name="offer" ></td></td>
<tr><td>Description:</td><td><input type="text"name="des" > </td></td>
<tr><td>    Offer Link:</td><td> <input  type="text" name="link" ></td></td>
<tr><td>    Pay Per weak:</td><td><input  type="text" name="pay" ></td></td>
</table>
<button class="button2" id="addoffer" align="Center">ADD</button> 
</fieldset>
</form>
```

query page

```
window.event.returnValue = false;
 $("#addoffer").click(function(e) {

$.post('addoffers.php', $('#postoffer').serialize(), function(data) {
                var code = $(data)[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
            if(code == 'success') {
                window.location="admin.php#confirm";}
             if(code=='error'){
                var id = parseInt($(data).attr('id'));
                switch(id) {
                    case 0:
                        $('#msg').html('Please fill all the field for add offer.');
                        window.location="admin.php#erorr";
                            break;
                    case 1:
        $('#msg').html('Sorry!This offer name has been already used.Plz change it');
                        window.location="admin.php#erorr";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                    {$('#msg').html('An error occurred, please try again.');
                        window.location="admin.php#erorr";
                            break;}
                    default:
                        $('#msg').html('An error occurred, please try again.');
                        window.location="admin.php#erorr";
                }
            }
        });
        return e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

php page

```
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['offer'], $_POST['des'], $_POST['link'], $_POST['pay'] , $_POST['stime'] , $_POST['smonth']) )
{
    $offername=$_POST['offer']; $description=$_POST['des'];$link=$_POST['link'];$description=str_replace("'",'39',$description);
    $pay=$_POST['pay'];
    $rating=$_POST['rate'];
    $stime=$_POST['stime'];
    $smonth=$_POST['smonth'];
    $data=mysql_query("select fname from offer where fname='$offername'");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($data);
    if($row==0)
    {   //echo $offername."<br>".$description."<br>".$link;
        $sql="insert into offer values ('NULL','$offername','$description','$link','$pay','$stime','$smonth')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        //echo $result;
        if($result)
        {echo "<success />";}
        else
        {
            echo "<error id='1'/>";}
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<error id='2'/>";
    }
}
else
{
echo "<error id='0'/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: can you check browser console (chrome - F12) and see if any errors?

Comment: Why did you post the JS code as images?

Comment: To lazy to type it lol

Comment: Actually don't no how to post the code that's why using image.

Comment: You write it like text, but start 0 indent at 4 indents on SO. There is a help button in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

The lesson you should learn here is:

Keep it simple.

Now, I am going to show you how to do it properly, but since you are simply redirecting to 2 different pages based on 4 different outcomes --- you probably shouldn't even use AJAX.

First, change your PHP script to simply `echo 'success';` or in the case of an error, just echo the number. Your error log

Then, you'll do yourself great good as a beginner to learn the longhand versions, first:

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'addOffers.php', 
        data: { offer : $('input[name="offer"]').val(), 
                des : $('input[name="offer"]').val(), 
                link : $('input[name="link"]').val(), 
                pay: $('input[name=""]').val() 
           }, // It would be a good thing if you gave those inputs IDs and selected by the IDs, instead.
    method: "POST", 
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == 'success') { 
             window.location "admin.php#confirm"; // redirecting honestly defeats the purpose of using AJAX --- 
         } else {
              switch(response){
                     case 0: 
                        //etc .... your code fits in, here.
                       break;
```

You see? that it much easier --- you don't need to use xml in your ajax...

Comment: What's difference between $.ajax() and $.post() method

Comment: `$.ajax` is just the long-hand method. Otherwise, they are the same.